# Store Properties for a SharePoint-hosted app

Tags: javascript, csom, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to figure of the best--or really any working way-- to store key/value pairs in a SharePoint hosted app. The pairs need to:

- Be loaded on start up, if the settings exist, otherwise use defaults.
- Be created on demand--i.e. a user can add a new setting in the UI, then I use that setting elsewhere in the code to make changes. For example a use a custom string of text as a list name instead of the app's default setting.

I've tried using the PropertyBag, but get an Access Denied error when trying to write to it.

I've also tried to use a list but had problems getting that technique to work correctly.

Does anyone have a suggestion of a good method and how it would be done. I'd be happy to revisit the techniques I've already attempted, if those are the best ways.

Keep in mind that this question should be restricted to things that work with a SharePoint-hosted app. That means that C#, and server-side code are out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution I ended up using--storing settings in a list in the hostweb of the app.

It's made up of a few functions seen below.

**CreateSettingsList:**

Create makes an ordinary list with the fields Title and Value, which I use to store a setting name and a value to be associated with it. This is called in the document ready function to ensure that a list has been created, and if one already has, it goes on and tries to read from it. If a list didn't exist before, I call a function to initialize default variable values in the list.

```
//___________________________________Create settings list________________________________________       
function createSettingsList()
{   
    // Create a SharePoint list with the name that the user specifies.
    var hostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
    var hostContext = new SP.AppContextSite(currentContext, hostUrl);
    var hostweb = hostContext.get_web();

    var listCreationInfo = new SP.ListCreationInformation();

    //title the list
    listCreationInfo.set_title("PTOAppSettings");

    //set the base type of the list
    listCreationInfo.set_templateType(100); //generic list
    listCreationInfo.set_description("A list for custom app settings. If you have uninstalled the Paid Time Off App with no intention of reinstalling, this list can be safely deleted.");

    var lists = hostweb.get_lists();
    //use the creation info to create the list
    var newList = lists.add(listCreationInfo);

    var fieldCollection = newList.get_fields();

    //add extra fields (columns) to the list & any other info needed.
    fieldCollection.addFieldAsXml('<Field Type="Text" DisplayName="Value" Name="Value" />', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.AddToDefaultContentType);
    newList.update();

    currentContext.load(fieldCollection);
    currentContext.load(newList);
    currentContext.executeQueryAsync(onSettingsListCreationSuccess, onSettingsListCreationFail);     
}

function onSettingsListCreationSuccess(){   
    //All is well.
    initializeSettings();

}

function onSettingsListCreationFail(sender, args) {
    //alert("We didn't create the list. Here's why: " + args.get_message());

    //If a list already exists, we expect the creation to fail, and instead try to read from the existing one.
    getSetting("VAR_CCEmail");
}
```

**Initialize:**

Initialize creates new list items for the variables that I may be storing in the future. I set their value to "" or null if they're not being used.

```
//___________________________________Initialize setting(s)________________________________________
function initializeSettings()
{
    //Get info to access host web
    var hostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
    var hostContext = new SP.AppContextSite(currentContext, hostUrl);
    var hostweb = hostContext.get_web();

    //Get list in host web
    var lstObject = hostweb.get_lists().getByTitle("PTOAppSettings");

    //Prepare an object to add a new list item.
    var listItemCreationInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    var newItem = lstObject.addItem(listItemCreationInfo);

    //Create item. You should repeat this for all the settings you want to track.
    newItem.set_item('Title', "VAR_CCEmail");
    newItem.set_item('Value', "");

    //Write this new item to the list
    newItem.update();

    currentContext.executeQueryAsync(onListItemSuccess, onListItemFailure);

    function onListItemSuccess() {

        //Load customizations, if any exist
        getSetting("VAR_CCEmail");
    }

    function onListItemFailure(sender, args) {
        bootbox.dialog({
            title: "Something went wrong!",
            message: "We were unable to initialize the app settings! Here's what we know about the problem: " + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace(),
            buttons: {
                success:{
                    label: "Ok"
                }
            }       
        });
    }
}
```

**Set:**

Set is a fairly straightforward function that accepts a setting name and a value and allows you to update the value stored in a given variable.

```
//___________________________________Set setting________________________________________
function setSetting(setting, value){

    //Get info to access host web
    var hostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
    var hostContext = new SP.AppContextSite(currentContext, hostUrl);
    var hostweb = hostContext.get_web();

    //Get list in host web
    var list = hostweb.get_lists().getByTitle("PTOAppSettings");

    //A caml query get the appropriate setting
    var queryXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>" + setting + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"
    var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
    query.set_viewXml(queryXml);

    var items = list.getItems(query);

    currentContext.load(items);
    currentContext.executeQueryAsync(onListItemSuccess, onListItemFailure);  
    function onListItemSuccess() {      
        //looking up a specific setting should only return one item in the array.
        var item = items.getItemAtIndex(0);
        //update the value for the item.
        item.set_item("Value", value);

        item.update();
    }

    function onListItemFailure(sender, args) {
        bootbox.dialog({
            title: "Something went wrong!",
            message: "We were unable to set app settings! Here's what we know about the problem: " + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace(),
            buttons: {
                success:{
                    label: "Ok"
                }
            }       
        });
    }
}
```

**Get:**

Get reads the list, finds the setting that you specified, and then determines if the Value associated with that setting "" or null or if it is an actual value. If it is an actual value, I write the value to the global variable that the program uses to do things with that setting.

```
//___________________________________Get setting________________________________________
function getSetting(setting) {
var hostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
var hostContext = new SP.AppContextSite(currentContext, hostUrl);
var hostweb = hostContext.get_web();
var list = hostweb.get_lists().getByTitle("PTOAppSettings");

//A caml query to get manager name for the record where user is equal to current user.
var queryXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>" + setting + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"
var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
query.set_viewXml(queryXml);

var items = list.getItems(query);

currentContext.load(items);
currentContext.executeQueryAsync(
function() //on success.
{
    //get first (and only) item.
    var item = items.getItemAtIndex(0);     
    var value = item.get_item("Value");

    //If the property is empty it hasn't been set.
    if (value === "" || value === null){
        //Return null to the appropriate global variable. Not all of the settings in this switch are implemented in the program yet, but may be later.
        switch(setting) {
            case "VAR_PaidTimeOff":
                paidTimeOffListName = "";
                break;
            case "VAR_Contacts":
                contactsListName = "";
                break;
            case "VAR_CCEmail":
                carbonCopyEmail = "";
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Return the value. Not all of the settings in this switch are implemented in the program yet, but may be later.
        switch(setting) {
            case "VAR_PaidTimeOff":
                paidTimeOffListName = value;
                break;
            case "VAR_Contacts":
                contactsListName = value;
                break;
            case "VAR_CCEmail":
                carbonCopyEmail = value;
                break;
        }
    }

}, 
function(sender,args){
    bootbox.dialog({
        title: "Something went wrong!",
        message: "We were unable to get app settings! Here's what we know about the problem: " + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace(),
        buttons: {
            success:{
                label: "Ok"
            }
        }       
    });
}); 
}
```

This could be expanded to include other functions to do other special tasks, for example you could make a "createSetting" function that would allow you to add new settings on the fly (one of the requirements I mentioned in my initial question). In my case, initializing a set group of settings fulfilled my needs, but other may want a way to write more.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks, I've been searching for a solution for my SP-Hosted app with this exact same problem, all I found was writing to web config files and code-behind solutions, but as you know; the nearest thing we get to that in SP-Hosted is JS. So thanks, your solution really helped me out :-) .